# Can't reach desired voltage on opamp output

Tags: operational-amplifier, amplifier

I have tried to make signal amplifier just to gain some op-amps knowledge, but unfortunately it doesn't work. It simply doesn't reach desired voltage (set by resistors). I have used my old cellphone headphone audio output as  an input for op-amp. The OPA454 was powered by +/-15 VDC from two 5V to 15V step-up conventers. The wiring looks like:
[image: wiring]

And SSs from scope with different gain. Please see peak-to-peak voltage below graphs:
[image: screen shot 1/3]
[image: screen shot 2/3]
[image: screen shot 3/3]

For some reason it can not exceed 10V peak-to-peak even through it should (based on my poor knowledge). Why it does so? One more thing is that I use adaptor so that it is possible for me to plug OPA454 to breadboard, but I am pretty sure it is designed / soldered correctly. I have tried swapping opamp to another one but it does't change anything. What could be potential issue?

Comment: You're clipping. Are you sure you're using +/- 15V?

Comment: @SeanM I am 100% sure. Just measured V+ to V- right on OPA454 pins and it is 30VDC.

Comment: Are you driving a load?  Could you, just for the sake of being complete, check that the scaling on your O-scope and probes is correct?  From the datasheet, if you're not driving less than a few k-ohms you should get to about 1V away from the rails.  So it's not rail-rail, but it's pretty close.

Comment: Try swapping the probes over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Hantek 6022BE scope is clipping at ±5V.

The [manual](http://www.hantek.com/down.aspx?url=http%3a%2f%2fwww.hantek.com%2fProduct%2fHantek6000%2fHantek6022BE_Manual.pdf) states:

> Max. Input +/- 5V(Without external attenuation)

You need a 10× probe if you want to measure voltages outside this range.

Comment: Well that was my issue. Setting switch on my current probe to 10x and then changing this value in software helped. The thing is that I was mislead by text on the scope - “max +/-35V”.  Will add appropriate tags in a moment so that other people could find this. Thanks from the bottom of my heart - I would never think of that. Note to self: RTFM.